# Como fazer um template layout com angularjs?

Tags: css, html5, angularjs

preciso de um template padrão para todas as telas da minha aplicação front-end como faço isso com angular-js? tem como?

Comment: Não entendi, poderia ser mais especifico? O que seria um template layout e como deverá funcionar?

Comment: eu tenho uma página onde eu vou criar o layout somente uma vez, e as outras páginas vão herdar o layout dessa página entende? @EmirMarques

Comment: Certo, mais vc vai alterar alguma coisa nesse layout ou será alterado somente o controller?

Comment: No layout não vou alterar nada só quando houver ajustes de layout , nenhuma interação vai ser feito nele , só nas páginas que herdaram dele @EmirMarques

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tem como sim @Jose. É só usar o `$routeProvider`.
Exemplo:

```
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "public/view/home.html",
        controller: "principalCtrl"

});
```

Dai na sua página (`index.html`) você coloca um `ng-view` no `body`
Exemplo:

```
<html ng-app="exemplo">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Login</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles/style.css"/>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="public/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="public/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="public/libs/angular/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
      <script src="public/libs/angular/angular-messages.js"></script>
      <script src="public/libs/angular/angular-flash.min.js"></script>
      <script src="public/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

      <script src="public/js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="public/js/controller/loginController.js"></script>
       <script src="public/js/controller/modalController.js"></script>
      <script src="public/js/config/routeConfig.js"></script>

      <script src="public/js/services/loginAPIService.js"></script> 
      <script src="public/js/value/configValue.js"></script>  


   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-view></div>
   </body>
   <html>
```

Resumindo, essa página `index.html` poderá se tornar seu template padrão, e voce chamará todas as outras páginas dentro dela.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno :)

Comment: Por nada, se tiver alguma dificuldade pra implementar essa solução é só comentar aqui que eu te ajudo a entender melhor.